# Creating a table of contents in Excel VBA which self updates

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I am working on a simple project in Excel. I have an inventory of equipment, each piece separated into a different worksheet. The very first worksheet is a table of contents with a list of all the equipment. Clicking on one takes the user to the worksheet for that specific piece of equipment. Currently, I have tied a macro to a button called New_Entry which creates a new sheet off of a template:

```
Sub New_Entry()
    Sheets.Add Type:= _
        "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Archive_Entry.xltx"
    ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End Sub
```

I am wondering if it is possible for the table of contents to be automatically updated with the content of, say, cell B2 (i.e. the name of that piece of equipment) of every new worksheet added via the button. This is the recorded macro for creating a hyperlink:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'Sheet1 (24)'!B1", TextToDisplay:="Sheet1 (24)!B1"
```

Comment: You can insert the code snippet into the subroutine New_Entry(), thus synchronizing the creation of new worksheet and adding the hyperlink to it.

Comment: True, but this would only execute the hyperlink for Sheet1 (24). I guess the question really is what's the proper syntax for "last sheet" and then "last sheet, B1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve the result, you can apply the solution I've described in my comment but instead of hard-coding the `Sheet` index apply `Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)` , i.e. the index corresponding to the last `Worksheet` as shown in the the following VBA code snippet:

```
Sub New_Entry()
    Sheets.Add Type:= _
    "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Archive_Entry.xltx"

    ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'Sheet1 (Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))'!B1", TextToDisplay:="Sheet1 (Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))!B1"
End Sub
```

Hope this may help

Comment: Thank you Alex! I thought I could activate sheet one, then use 

Activecell.End(xlDown).Offset(1,0).Select 

to highlight the next empty cell in the Table of contents column and use your code to have the B2 cell content copied and hyperlinked onto it. However, that does not seem to be the case. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are welcome! You could go farther modifying your code in correspondence with additional requirements/business logic. Please mark the question answered if satisfied, and if you have more questions please do not hesitate to post them separately. Good luck with your project. Best regards,