# Create a table of contents where the topics are hyperlinked back to the cell location

Tags: excel, vba

My question is similar to “[Creating a table of contents in Excel VBA which self updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035030/creating-a-table-of-contents-in-excel-vba-which-self-updates)”

I have a workbook that needs a Table of Contents (TOC) on a worksheet (Sheet2), where the topics are hyperlinked back to the cell location on Sheet1.

I have a list of topics on Sheet2 Column B with the Cell location on Sheet1 in Column C.

I need, by formula or code, to copy the cell location from column C and add it as the Sub-address with sheet1 as the address and hyperlink the corresponding topic in Column B.

I have recorded the following:

```
Sub Macro5()
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _ Anchor:=Selection, _ Address:="", _
      SubAddress:="'Test Script'!A8", TextToDisplay:="277 - Rejected" 
End Sub
```

I need to loop and replace the variables for SubAddress and TestToDisplay.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider using [code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) for your sample code to make it simpler to read.

Comment: Please add a link to the question which you are referencing. In addition, you really should read up more on VBA's syntax and how to use it a bit more before you attempt writing macros by hand - the code generated by a recorded macro is much different than what a programmer might write to complete a repetitive task.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/visual-basic-conceptual-topics

Comment: Here is the link to the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035030/creating-a-table-of-contents-in-excel-vba-which-self-updates

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I am new to the site, and I appreciate the coaching.